# CSS last of type does not match while still loading

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, opera

I think I discovered a bug in chrome and opera and would like a solution to make the css selector `section:last-of-type` work while the document is still loading. The bug only appears while the document is still loading: here's a minimal example in NodeJS to expose the bug:

What happens is that last-of-type does not match while the document is still loading. In IE it matches, then matches twice, then matches correctly again when loaded. It works fine in Firefox.

*last-of-type.js*

```
"use strict";
const http = require(`http`);

const PORT = 8080;

const htmlStart = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>html streaming</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>

section {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

section:last-of-type {
    animation: comin 1.4s ease 0s;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes comin {
    0% {
      left: 100%;
    }
    100% {
      left: 0;
    }
}

section:not(:last-of-type) {
   animation: comout 1.4s ease 0s;
   left: -100%;
   opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes comout {
    0% {
      left: 0;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      left: -100%;
      opacity: 0;
    }
}
</style>
    <script>
        var headLoaded = Date.now();
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
           console.log((Date.now() - headLoaded) / 1000);
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>last-of-type test</h1>

    <section>
        <h2>First slide</h2>
        <p>Some text 111111111</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>2</h2>
        <p>22222222222222</p>
    </section>


`;

const htmlEnd = `
<p>html finised loading</p>
</body></html>`;


const INTERVAL = 8000; // ms
const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  response.setHeader(`Content-Type`, `text/html`);
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.write(htmlStart);
  setTimeout(function () {
        response.write(`<section>
            <h2>3</h2>
            <p>33333333333</p>
        </section>`);
  }, INTERVAL);
  setTimeout(function () {
        response.end(htmlEnd);
  }, 3 * INTERVAL);
});

server.listen(PORT);
console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`);
```

The same loaded all at once works just fine. It confirms that the syntax is correct.

*last-of-type-test.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>html streaming</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>

section {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

section:last-of-type {
    animation: comin 1.4s ease 0s;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes comin {
    0% {
      left: 100%;
    }
    100% {
      left: 0;
    }
}

section:not(:last-of-type) {
   animation: comout 1.4s ease 0s;
   left: -100%;
   opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes comout {
    0% {
      left: 0;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      left: -100%;
      opacity: 0;
    }
}
</style>
    <script>
        var headLoaded = Date.now();
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
           console.log((Date.now() - headLoaded) / 1000);
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>last-of-type test</h1>

    <section>
        <h2>First slide</h2>
        <p>some text</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>2</h2>
        <p>22222222222222</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>3</h2>
        <p>33333333333</p>
    </section>
</body></html>
```

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: if you think you've found a bug in the browsers, you should report it to them. You're not gaining anything posting here unless you want to ask a question about how to get around the bug.

Comment: you can do it Simba, I would like to find a solution

Comment: Can you post a link to your github repo (assuming it's not private).

Comment: https://github.com/GrosSacASac/JavaScript-Set-Up/tree/master/general/html-streaming npm i npm run demo3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround is to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) while the page is loading. There you can get a list of all elemets of `section` and give the last element an special class `last`. The `MutationObserver` is called on every dom change, even if the page is still loading. When the page is loaded you can remove this observer.

```
"use strict";
const http = require(`http`);

const PORT = 8080;

const htmlStart = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>html streaming</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>

section {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

section:not(:last-of-type) {
    animation: comout 1.4s ease 0s;
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

section:last-of-type, section.last {
    animation: comin 1.4s ease 0s;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes comin {
    0% {
    left: 100%;
    }
    100% {
    left: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes comout {
    0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
    }
}
</style>
    <script>
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
            var list = document.querySelectorAll("section");
            if (list.length === 0) return;
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                list[i].classList.remove("last");
            }
            list[list.length - 1].classList.add("last");
        });
        var headLoaded = Date.now();
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            console.log((Date.now() - headLoaded) / 1000);
            observer.disconnect();
            var list = document.querySelectorAll("section");
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                list[i].classList.remove("last");
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        observer.observe(document.body, { attributes: true, childList: true })
    </script>
    <h1>last-of-type test</h1>

    <section>
        <h2>First slide</h2>
        <p>Some text 111111111</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>2</h2>
        <p>22222222222222</p>
    </section>


`;

const htmlEnd = `
<p>html finised loading</p>
</body></html>`;


const INTERVAL = 8000; // ms
const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
response.setHeader(`Content-Type`, `text/html`);
response.writeHead(200);
response.write(htmlStart);
setTimeout(function () {
        response.write(`<section>
            <h2>3</h2>
            <p>33333333333</p>
        </section>`);
}, INTERVAL);
setTimeout(function () {
        response.end(htmlEnd);
}, 3 * INTERVAL);
});

server.listen(PORT);
console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`);
```

The observer must be connected after the `<bod>` tag. Otherwise `document.body` is `null`.

I put the css selector `section:not(:last-of-type)` before the positive match to avoid the usage of `!important` directives.

Comment: almost a polyfill to :last-of-type